# C# non-static class inside static class JINT

Tags: c#, inner-classes, jint

Hi trying to make a class inside a static class to use in JINT but when it's referenced I get an error

C# code

```
namespace Hi {
    public static class Ok {
        public class Wowa {
            public Wowa(){}
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to make a new one in JavaScript I get an error "the object cannot be used as a constructor" from JINT

```
var k = new Hi.Ok.Wowa()
```

Am I doing this right? How can I set up the C# to be able to use the above code in JavaScript from JINT?

BTW IF instead of "Ok" being a static class, rather a namespace, it works, but I want it as a class because I want to have static methods in it also

Comment: You don't have to have a static class to have static methods.  You need a static class for extension methods but that doesn't sound like what you're trying to do.

Comment: @mikej I'm just trying to be able to write the JavaScript code like in the question, I don't care how the c# is set up, how do I do it? Whether I make the surrounding class static or not it so gives the same result

Answer (score 2):

you cant use none-static class in a static class ([ReadThis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)) but if you remove (static) in your frist class

```
  namespace Hi {
    public class Ok {
        public class Wowa {
            public Wowa(){}
        }
    }
}
```

and it can be said that it does not make much difference because (Static) only makes subcategories of your class have to use (Static).
But if you want your class to be impossible to build on variables, you can use abstract([ReadThis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract))

```
namespace Hi {
    public abstract class Ok {
        public class Wowa {
            public Wowa(){}
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Main()
{
    Ok k = new Ok();//Error
}
```

Comment: I mean in JINT i can call `new Hi.Ok.Wowa()`?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have this:

```
namespace Hi
{
  public static class Ok
  {
    public class Wowa
    {
         public Wowa() { }
         public static string MyStaticMethod() => "Hello from 'Static Method'";
         public string MyNormalMethod() => "Hello from 'Normal Method'";
    }
  }
}
```

It's possible to use non-static class `Wowa` by making an instance of it , and then you can call `MyNormalMethod` of that instance (you can only call **not-static** method within instance of that class).

```
 Hi.Ok.Wowa wowa = new Hi.Ok.Wowa();
 wowa.MyNormalMethod();
```

And without making any instance of `Wowa` you can call **static** method within it, like this:

```
Hi.Ok.Wowa.MyStaticMethod();
```

Finally you can see working code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vzIw7C).